# How take a screenshot of a specific webelement using selenium and java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='e-dropdown-btn_16']")).click();
       List <WebElement>dropdownoptions=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='menu']/li"));
        for (WebElement value :dropdownoptions)
        {
            String valuetoselect=value.getText();
            
            if(valuetoselect.equalsIgnoreCase("Fit one page"))
            {
            value.click();
            }
           
         }
driver.wait(2000);
        WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='container_editor_viewerContainer']"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                   File a = new File("c:/a.png");
                  js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",element); 
                  File b =element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                  FileHandler.copy(b, a);
```

Comment: Whats the issue in this ?

Comment: I cant able to click a dropdown and take the webelement screenshot

Comment: mean the option ?

Comment: //div[@id='container_editor_viewerContainer']" what is this element

Comment: NO i have to first click a button and select a list(Its an zoom out option I have to select fit to page) from the dropdown and take screenshot of the webelement

Comment: it is an button

Comment: whats the issue you are facing with the current code

Comment: The screen shot is not saved in the loaction after using for loops Before using it the screenshot saves in the location

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: Before For loop I didint get any error but no it shows unable to locate element

Comment: did you check if element is present ? after seelcting the option ?

Comment: @shiva try to change the place where you're storing your file. Usually regular user is not allowed to save file to root of `C:/` drive. Try to save it to some folder instead.

Comment: @AlexeyR. its saving before the for loop , issue is element not found . after clicking the option element is change and author is not checking or that element

Comment: @PDHide yes I checked in DOM

Comment: can you chang driver.sleep() , Thread.sleep(5000) and try

Comment: @PDHide Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='container_editor_viewerContainer']"}I got this error

Comment: @shiva seelect the option goto devtools and check whether yo uare manually able to find that element after you click the dropdown and select the option

Comment: @PDHideIt is an list it has 10 elements in the same name so I used for loop to find using text(inside ul tag there are 10 li tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
...
driver.get("https://youtube.com");
WebElement start = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#start"));
File file = start.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
Files.copy(file.toPath(), Path.of("/tmp/start.png"));
```

**P.S.** - The issue that might prevent your file to be saved is that you're trying to save it to root of `C` drive. Try to save it to some folder.